# Postgres Psql to file

Tags: postgresql, csv, psql

I have a bash script, with a call to PSQL, which executes a query, and then using a WHILE loop, I print the output to a file.   Something like:

```
psql -U zrec -d zrec -t -c "SELECT .........;" \    | while read -a Record; do
  printf "${Record[0]},${Record[1]}\n"  >> /tmp/file.csv
done
```

The query has grown into a very large query.  Also, I now need to pass a date variable to the query.   So, I'm thinking to take this hard coded query, and put it into a .sql file, call it, pass the date variable, and print the output to a file.

Oracle makes this easy with SPOOL and &1, etc.......

Is there a way I can:

1. Call the bash script
2. Have the script call my_query.sql, and pass it a date parameter
3. Put the query output into a file

Seems like it should be simple, but is proving not to be.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate a `csv` file, don't use spool or something similar, use `\copy`. No need to loop.

Something like:

```
\copy (SELECT ....) to '/tmp/file.csv' with (format csv, header true)
```

It's typically easier to put anything that is longer than a few words into a separate SQL script rather than passing it using `-c "..."` which also opens up many nested quoting problems.

So if you put the above into a file e.g. `export.sql`, all you need is:

```
psql -U zrec -d zrec -f export.sql`
```

Comment: Actually, I have 1 more question, if I can put it here:   Using your method, if the query needs a parameter, how can I pass it to the copy command?